# Get a click-able link while using string.replace c# mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to change certain word by click-able link with the Replace function. The way the application works is when I put a label somewhere on the page I can dynamically choose which word can be a link.

My problem happen when I replace the text with the  tag. Once I load the page, I don't get a link, I only get the raw text. Here's the sample code: (Excuse the none optimized code, I'm just trying to make it works)

```
var text = ViewBag.isEnglish ? Model.TextEnglish : Model.TextFrench; //Get the text either in french or english

int counter = 0;
foreach(var option in Model.FieldItems)
{
    text = text.Replace(ViewBag.isEnglish ? option.TextEnglish : option.TextFrench, "{" + counter + "}");//Replace the selected text to {#}
    counter++;
}
counter = 0;
foreach(var option in Model.FieldItems)
{

    if (ViewBag.isEnglish) {
        text = text.Replace("{" + counter + "}",string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" target=\"_blank\">{1}</a>", option.Value, option.TextEnglish));//Replace the {#} with the <a> tag here
    }
    else
    {
        //text = text.Replace("{" + counter + "}", "<a href=\""+option.Value+"\" target=\"_blank\">"+option.TextFrench+"</a>");
    }
    counter++;
}
if (ViewBag.isEnglish)
{
    Model.TextEnglish = text;
}
else
{
    Model.TextFrench = text;
}
<div id="field@(Model.FieldID)" class="field form-group @Model.Classes.Format("Field")" data-fieldid="@Model.FieldID">
    <span for="@id" class=" @Model.Classes.Format("Label")">@(ViewBag.isEnglish ? Model.TextEnglish : Model.TextFrench)</span>//Show the text here      
    </div>
```

I am trying to not use the Microsoft helper. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Is there a way to like not get a raw text from this? 
Thank you for reading and answering

Comment: I imagine you still need to render with `@Html.Raw` when you output `Model.TextEnglish|French`, even though you used it in the code

Comment: `@(ViewBag.isEnglish ? Model.TextEnglish : Model.TextFrench)` -> `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.isEnglish ? Model.TextEnglish : Model.TextFrench)` should work

Comment: I suppose there is no other way. Thank you !

Comment: Yep, otherwise it just sees it as plaintext and writes it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using just

```
@(ViewBag.isEnglish ? Model.TextEnglish : Model.TextFrench)
```

try using

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.isEnglish ? Model.TextEnglish : Model.TextFrench)
```

which will render out the HTML instead of just plaintext